# UIView Animation on multiple UIImageViews in ARC

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, automatic-ref-counting, uiviewanimation

I have an animation in my app that grows a UIImageView and then shrinks it (really two animations). Throughout the app this may happen on several different UIImageViews. I found a way to do this that worked really well, but it now doesn't seem to be compatible with Automatic Reference Counting. Here is my code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"growImage" context:imageName];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
imageName.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

and then:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(UIImageView *)context {
    if (animationID == @"growImage") {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"shrinkImage" context:context];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    context.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

This worked perfectly and I was very happy with it, until I tried converting my project to ARC. I now get the error "Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'void *' is disallowed with ARC" on these lines in which I try to pass a UIImageView as the context for the animation:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"growImage" context:imageName];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"shrinkImage" context:context];
```

Does anybody know of another way that I can alert the "animationDidStop" function of which UIImageView I want it to act on that would be compliant with ARC?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"growImage"
                context:(__bridge void*)imageName];
imageName.transform = ...
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Warning: the straight `__bridge` only works if you already have a strong reference to `imageName` elsewhere that outlasts the animation completion. Otherwise ARC will get rid of it before the handler is called. If that applies to you, see the good answers here for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809107/passing-objects-safely-as-opaque-context-params-under-arc

Answer (score 2):

Any reason you are not using the much simpler block based animation?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animation:^{
    imageName.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2);
} completion ^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animation:^{
        imageName.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
    }];
}];
```

Comment: One nice thing about passing in the value of a UIImageView is that I don't have to put the same completion block for every animation. I do this shrink animation on dozens of images throughout the app. The bigger issue for me is that I believe these block based animations are only available in iOS4 and I like to still target my apps to users with iPads on OS 3.2