# beginAnimations with "context"variable in ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, automatic-ref-counting, bridge

The question partially similar to existing ones but I still get error with memory management.

The following non-ARC code work:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:... context:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] retain]];
```

and somewhere in didStopSelector:

```
NSNumber * n = (NSNumber *)context;
...
[n release];
```

I tried to remove retain/release and to add copy (and combined these ways) but with no effect.

Additionally I saw another similar question:

[UIView Animation on multiple UIImageViews in ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157105/uiview-animation-on-multiple-uiimageviews-in-arc)

They pass `imageName` variable as `context` but they don't describe if it is retained or autoreleased.

Questions:

1)How to convert my code to ARC correctly?

2)Is there any difference in code if you pass retained/autoreleased context (of cousre, if autoreleased will work in general)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `__bridge_retained` to retain object and cast it to `void*`

```
void *context = (__bridge_retained void *)( @1000 );
```

and then in `animationDidStop` you have to transfer ownership with `__bridge_transfer`. At this point ARC should naturally release the object in current autorelease pool.

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(void *)context {
   NSNumber *n = (__bridge_transfer id)context;
}
```

Alternatively you can switch to block based API and reference views directly.

Comment: Ok, and what about `__bridge` and similar ones?

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov of course my original answer was incorrect. I updated the answer. Could you please test if it's compilable?